# Connect pyspark with mongodb from google-colab

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory

I want to connect pyspark and google colab. 
I have information in mongodb on cloud (mlab).

With google colab, I execute this script:

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.3.2/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!tar xf spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!pip install -q findspark
!pip install pyspark

import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7"
```

And, in my local environment I execute the py-script with this line:

```
spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.5 wordcount.py
```

But, on cloud I can't execute it directly...

Exactly, the initial script is:

```
uri_in = "mongodb://{}:{}@{}.speeches".format(mongo_user, mongo_password, mongo_url)

uri_out = "mongodb://{}:{}@{}.wordcount_out".format(
    mongo_user, mongo_password, mongo_url
)

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("discursos.counter")
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", uri_in)
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", uri_out)
    .getOrCreate()
)

df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
```

Can I connect mongodb google-colab by pyspark?

thanks!